# String boot: Launch bunch of consumers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm running against an issue related with how to process a bunch of consumers.

I need all consumers ends regardless of whether a checked/unchecked exception is thrown.

I mean, currently my springboot service needs to process a bunch of `URI` (download, store, save metadata on database and so on so forth...):

```
public List<URI> getURIs() {//...}
```

and

```
public void handleURI(URI uri) {
    //download URI
    //store at mongo
    //get statistics
}
```

`handleURI` can throw unchecked exceptions like `DuplicatedKeyException`...

Currently, I'm processing them using java streams, but when a consumer throws any exception, stream is stopped:

```
this.getURIs().stream().forEach(this::handleURI);
```

I need to process all `uri` regardless of whether any of them had any problem.

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the method call in try/catch block like this :

```
this.getURIs().stream().forEach(uri - > {
  try { 
    this.handleURI(uri)
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //handle the particular uri failed case.
  }
});
```